# Go to Action in Controller on click with parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

When a dynamic button is clicked, I want to go to the action in the controller.

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {
    var var1 = "test1"
    var var2 = "test2"
    var var3 = "test3";

    location.href = '<%= Url.Action("Action","Controller") %>';
});
```

This is fine, but if I try and add the variables to the action, everything goes down hill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the scopes. There is no way to pass a `client-side` javascript variable to the `server-side` execution, so you could generate a url concatening the values, for sample:

```
var var1 = "test1"
var var2 = "test2"
var var3 = "test3";

location.href = '<%= Url.Action("Action", "Controller") %>?var1=' + var1 + '&var2=' + var2 + '&var3=' + var3;
```

Since you have these parameters in the `action`, it should work fine, for sample:

```
public ActionResult Action(string var1, string var2, string var3)
{
   //....
}
```

Comment: I absolutely was confusing my scopes, this worked great. You're kind of my hero right now. - I'll mark as the right answer tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a placeholder value while generating URL then use `.replace()`

Assumig your controller as

```
public ActionResult Action(string p1, string p2, string p3)
{
}
```

*JavaScript*

```
var var1 = "test1"
var var2 = "test2"
var var3 = "test3";

var url = '<%= Url.Action("Action","Controller", new { p1 = -1, p2 = -2, p3=-3  }) %>';
location.href = url.replace('-1',var1).replace('-2',var2).replace('-3',var3);
```